# I create a unit test project in python and got some error like below

Tags: python, selenium

My code :

from selenium import webdriver
import unittest
import HtmlTestRunner
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

class bimobAppsTest(unittest.TestCase):

```
@classmethod
def setUpClass(cls):
    cls.driver = webdriver.chrome(executable_path='../E:/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe')
    cls.time.sleep(1)
    cls.driver.maximize_window()


def test_HomePageTitle(self) :
    self.driver.get("http://apps.BIMOBApps")
    print(self.driver.title)
    # self.assertAlmostEqual(self.driver.title)

def test_Login(self):
    self.driver.get("http://apps.BIMOBApps")
    self.driver.find_element_by_id("txtUserName").send_keys("111")
    self.driver.find_element_by_id("txtPassword").send_keys("11111")
    self.driver.find_element_by_id("btnLoginUsers").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

@classmethod
def tearDownClass(cls):
    cls.driver.quit()
    print("Test Complete")
```

if **name** == '**main**':
unittest.main()

And error :

Testing started at 2:11 PM ...
D:\Python\Scripts\python.exe "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.2.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pycharm_jb_unittest_runner.py" --target Test.MyTestCase.test_Login
Launching unittests with arguments python -m unittest Test.MyTestCase.test_Login in C:\Users\faisal.hossain\PycharmProjects\pythonProject

Ran 0 tests in 0.004s

FAILED (errors=1)

Failure
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\unittest\suite.py", line 163, in _handleClassSetUp
setUpClass()
File "C:\Users\faisal.hossain\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\Test.py", line 10, in setUpClass
cls.driver=webdriver.chrome(executable_path='../E:/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe')
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Process finished with exit code 1

Assertion failed

Assertion failed

Assertion failed

Comment: `webdriver.chrome` apparently is a module and not a function. Did you maybe want to call `webdriver.Chrome` instead? Have a look at Example 2 of the [docs](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/index.html#drivers)